Why are no strong verbs spelled with ⟨oa⟩ in the past tense?
Why don't noncompound irregular verbs forms have oa spelling?
Generally speaking, in cases where an Old English ⟨ā⟩ or ⟨o⟩ becomes /oʊ/ in Modern English, the result may be written with either ⟨oa⟩ or ⟨o…e⟩:

rād > road, grānian > groan
col > coal, fola > foal
— vs. —
stān > stone, rāp > rope
nosu > nose, smoca > smoke

The choice of which word ended up with which variant is seemingly arbitrary, according to this previous answer.
However, in strong verbs that in the past tense or past participle have an o vowel that corresponds to Old English ⟨ā, o⟩, it’s always written ⟨o…e⟩, never ⟨oa⟩, even when ⟨oa⟩ would be equally possible:

rād > rode (not *road)
drāf > drove (not *droav)
wrāt > wrote (not *wroat)
(ġe)brocen > broken (not *broaken)
(ġe)stolen > stolen (not *stoalen)
(ġe)toren > torn (not *toarn)

There isn’t a single example of ⟨oa⟩ in such forms, so we have a regularity within strong verbs. Is it known why the spelling settled so consistently on ⟨o…e⟩ in this particular place when it’s so varied everywhere else?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
